# I am getting an error while deploying my app to azure through git repository

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, azure, deployment

[This is the message I am getting Log stream from Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LzpT.png)

[This is my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwfkA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have an error in your Azure log of `Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing`. When you set your deployment script, did you remember to run `npm install`? The deployment on azure is running `npm start` but has not installed the node modules so you need to install them as well.